# Find and Replace numbers in a string

Tags: t-sql

If I input a string as given below, I should be able to convert as mentioned below.

Ex 1: String - 5AB89C should be converted as 0000000005AB0000000089C

Ex 2: String GH1HJ should be converted as GH0000000001HJ

Ex 3: String N99K7H45 should be B0000000099K0000000007H0000000045

Each number should be complimented with 10 leading zeros including the number. In Ex:1, number 5 is complemented with 9 leading zeros making 10 digits, same way 89 is complimented with 8 leading zeros making total of 10 digits. Alphabets and any special characters should be untouched.

Comment: Do you have a _specific_ question? (Or _any_ question? It just looks like you've stated requirements.) What have you tried? What database software are you using, e.g. SQL Server?

Comment: What is the expected output for "00000000000000000042", i.e. should it be trimmed to 10 characters? "9876543210123456789"?

Answer (score 2):

Once you get a copy of [PatternSplitCM](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/splitting-strings-based-on-patterns) This is easy as pie.

Here's how we do it with one value:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(8000) = '5AB89C' 

SELECT   CASE f.[matched] WHEN 1 THEN '00000000'+'' ELSE '' END + f.item 
FROM     dbo.patternsplitCM(@String,'[0-9]') AS f
ORDER BY f.ItemNumber
FOR XML PATH('');
```

**Returns:** 000000005AB0000000089C

Now against a table:

```
-- sample data
DECLARE @table TABLE (StringId INT IDENTITY, String VARCHAR(8000));
INSERT @table(String)
VALUES('5AB89C'),('GH1HJ'),('N99K7H45');

SELECT t.StringId, oldstring = t.String, newstring = f.padded
FROM   @table AS t
CROSS APPLY 
(
  SELECT   CASE f.[matched] WHEN 1 THEN '00000000'+'' ELSE '' END + f.item 
  FROM     dbo.patternsplitCM(t.String,'[0-9]') AS f
  ORDER BY f.ItemNumber
  FOR XML PATH('')
) AS f(padded);
```

**Returns:**

```
StringId    oldstring         newstring
----------- ----------------- --------------------------------------
1           5AB89C            000000005AB0000000089C
2           GH1HJ             GH000000001HJ
3           N99K7H45          N0000000099K000000007H0000000045
```

... and that's it. The code to create PatternSplitCM is below.

**PatternSplitCM Code:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.PatternSplitCM
(
       @List                VARCHAR(8000) = NULL
       ,@Pattern            VARCHAR(50)
) RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS 
RETURN
    WITH numbers AS (
      SELECT TOP(ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@List), 0))
       n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
      FROM
      (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) d (n),
      (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) e (n),
      (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) f (n),
      (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) g (n))
    SELECT
      ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MIN(n)),
      Item = SUBSTRING(@List,MIN(n),1+MAX(n)-MIN(n)),
      Matched
     FROM (
      SELECT n, y.Matched, Grouper = n - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY y.Matched,n)
      FROM numbers
      CROSS APPLY (
          SELECT Matched = CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@List,n,1) LIKE @Pattern THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ) y
     ) d
     GROUP BY Matched, Grouper
```